# Error when runing the program, but not when compiling it

Tags: java

Why isn't there an error at line marked with //1 when you compile the program, but there is one when you run it. I am new to Java so I try to better understand how classes work.

```
class A{
private int x;
}

class B extends A{
private int a;
void exec(){
    System.out.println("test");
}

static void function(A a){
    ((B)a).exec();//1
}

public static void main(String argv[]){
    B.function(new A());
    B.function(new B());
}
}
```

Comment: B is an A but the other way around isn't true. Therefore you cannot cast A to B. Try reading [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, Java allows you to cast a reference type to another reference type if it is possible that the cast will succeed, i.e. it's possible that it won't throw a `ClassCastException`.  It can't guarantee that it will succeed, of course, because as you've seen, a reference to an `A` could be referring to a `B` object, but it might not be a `B` object.

[Section 5.5.1 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1) elaborates on what causes the compiler error if both the original reference type (S) and the casting type (T) are class types:

> Given a compile-time reference type S (source) and a compile-time reference type T (target), a casting conversion exists from S to T if no compile-time errors occur due to the following rules.
>
> If S is a class type:
>
> - If T is a class type, then either |S| <: |T|, or |T| <: |S|. Otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.

(The notation `<:` in the JLS means "is a subtype of".)

Because `B` is a subtype of `A`, your cast of a `A` to a `B` is legal, because it is possible for it to succeed.  By contrast, casting to an unrelated type, e.g. `String`, will generate a compiler error; that cast cannot succeed.

Answer (score 0):

You say you get an error runnning the application, I am guessing the error in this case is `ClassCastException` as `A` is not a `B`

Note this is a Runtime Exception :

see: [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html/)

Read more about Checked and UnChecked Exceptions here :

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html

http://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/java-checked-unchecked-exceptions-with-examples/

Comment: shouldn't the compiler report this error when you compile the program, and not only when you run it?

Comment: No it would not as `ClassCastException extends RuntimeException`... Meaning it is not a checked exception(one that will show you red-lines by your IDE or failed to compile.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that every `B` is an `A` (since `B` extends `A`), but the converse is not true: not every `A` is a `B`. Therefore, sometimes, you *may* be able to cast an `A` to a `B` as you did in your code above. The compiler can however identify issues when there is a clear casting violation. For example, consider the case of trying to cast a `BufferedReader` to an `Integer` : Since `Integer` is not in the class hierarchy of `BufferedReader`, the cast will fail with the error:

> Cannot cast from Stage to Integer

The reason you receive an exception only at runtime is that a `ClassCastException` is a [`RuntimeException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html). Any exception that extends `RuntimeException` is not *checked* at compile time. From the JavaDoc for [`Exception`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html):

> The class `Exception` and any subclasses that are not also subclasses of `RuntimeException` are checked exceptions. Checked exceptions need to be declared in a method or constructor's throws clause if they can be thrown by the execution of the method or constructor and propagate outside the method or constructor boundary.